# Restrict simultaneous access to a particular view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, multiple-instances

I have a View which is used to create some tasks. I want to restrict the users from opening more than once instance of that view at a time.

Is there any way in which we can achieve this, preferably from the application without database involvement. Although any suggestion on resolving this using the DB is most welcome.

I found another [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017865/mvc-restrict-multiple-access-to-an-action-result-view) related to my concern, to which I did not found any answers, so creating a separate thread.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason for attempting to do this?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I want to restrict the user from working on more than one task at a time.

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to reliably do that. If you were to set a flag in a controller indicating the user was _working on a task_ (in order to check it and prevent another task being accessed) then if the user closed the browser tab, the server would have no knowledge of it and would not be able to reset the flag.

Comment: Assuming we are setting a flag in the controller, I suppose we can reset it via ajax call on window unload, but this does not seem to be an efficient way of handling this issue.

Comment: Agreed, and also what happens if the connection was lost? Best I can think of is to have a table with the UserID and CurrentTaskID fields. When a task is requested, check if there is a matching row, if not add it, but if one exists, return the same task, and once the task has been submitted, remove the corresponding row (would all need to be done in a transaction of course)